# Unable to Load Image Url in Xamarin Forms Embedding

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am trying to load an Image in Xamarin Forms ImageView from a remote Url.

```
testImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri (new Uri ("https://some/url/with/ image.jpg"));
```

However, images from this particular domain doesn't load the image.

I have tried using FFImageLoading with Caching Enabled. However the image doesn't load either.

Other Images I tried, load without any issue. Example:

```
testImage.Source = ImageSource.FromUri (new Uri ("https://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/c0c6b4a67cbe2f36c78463f35beaa2df25b5a2f3/c=0-335-2700-2365&r=x404&c=534x401/local/-/media/2018/01/18/USATODAY/USATODAY/636518629737073874-02568-4-DQPK-PR-Image-CR2.jpg"));
```

I am using Xamarin Forms 2.5.1

Other things I have tried was changing the HTTP Client Implementation for iOS project.

I have also tried handling the Error Event of FFImageView.
It gives the following error:

```
{System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Forbidden   at FFImageLoading.Cache.DownloadCache+<DownloadAsync>d__17.MoveNext () [0x00111] in C:\projects\ffimageloading\source\FFImageLoading.Common\Cache\DownloadCache.cs:103  --- End of stack
```

Comment: 403 Forbidden means the server is refusing to serve the request.  Perhaps there is hotlinking logic in place that is trying to prevent you from using their images without authorization?

Comment: Can you access that image from browser?

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Yes I Could access the url in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

use private tab in your browser and see if you can access the image from there.

I think you are logged in to some service and the cookies are allowing your to view the image.

You can also try Postman https://www.getpostman.com which will make your API calls much easier.

The response can be almost anything. Json, HTML, XML, and Images.
Just put the url there and use the GET method to see the response.

Comment: It returns a jpeg image. Working with Postman as well as in Private Mode Web Browser. It simply doesn't show up on the Xamrin.Forms Image View.

Comment: @Prasun The image url starts with `Http` or `Https`? , If http ,please refer to https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/55923/sdwebimage-wont-show-some-images-on-device-but-all-work-on-simulator

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT url starts with https and the server is AKAMAI Image server.

Comment: Is that image public ? Maybe as Jason said, it needs authorization or something else to access the image.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT Op said that he can access it from private tab and postman. No authorization is there unless provided